# Error al procesar la peticion, codigo de error 200 PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

He estado instalando y desistalando xampp 20 veces porqué me sale siempre este error,
alguien me puede ayudar?? Un saludo![image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, me respondo yo mismo, aqui esta la solucion:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtsW0dzTCoU

Comment: Revisar [answer].